# Object member allocation

Tags: c++

I understand that objects initialized with 'new' are allocated from the heap, but what about their members? For example, I have class A:

```
class A
{
        private: int a;   //here "a" should be on stack  
};
```

Then I have object A defined in following code respectively

```
A a;

A *ap = new A();
```

Now the first statement places `a` on stack and `ap` will be in the heap, but how about `a.a` and `ap->a`? Are they with their parent objects?

Comment: The instance members of an object are a part of the storage of said object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by definition if an object is on the heap, so are its members, and likewise for the stack.

An object is really just a chunk of memory, so because the object contains the member, thats where the memory for the member will be.

Answer (score 0):

The members are part of the object, just like with a `struct`.